# what is ftell() and fseek() function in vb.net?

Tags: vb.net, function

In php program, we use ftell() to returns the current position of the file read/write pointer and use fseek() to seeks on a file pointer.

In vb.net program, is there the function like that ?

Comment: There is no such thing as a file pointer in VB.NET.  You use various particular types to read and write files in various particular ways.  You need to first determine which type you need to use and then consult the documentation for that type to see what members it has and what they each do to determine which you need to use for any particular task.  You should never be asking a question here without doing that first.  Reading the documentation should ALWAYS be your first option when you need help.  That's why it is accessible from the Help menu in VS.

Comment: Also, be aware that something like a `StreamReader` will actually sit on top of a `FileStream` when reading from files, so you have both objects to use for different things if required.

Comment: Ok, thanks for the advice